# How to pass hadoop configurations when submit job in my own driver class using commad line?

Tags: hadoop

I am talking about submit hadoop job from a machine outside of the cluster.
So here is the case,
in my linux desktopn, I have all the hadoop jar files in the class path.
Usually in command line you use this kind of command :

```
java -Dproc_jar -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=/cdh4/hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2/bin/../logs -    Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log
-Dhadoop.home.dir=/cdh4/hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2/bin/.. -Dhadoop.id.str=zhaoyong -   Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
-Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -classpath
/cdh4/hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2 .......(here ignore lots of jar files) 
org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
/cdh4/hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2/hadoop-examples-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2.jar
wordcount /golfnew.csv /testout
```

This can work because I have core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml,mapred-site.xml in my classpath.
So my question is, If I want to submit the job to multiple cluster, how can I pass the configuration in commandline, instead of using the fixed xml files in the classpath? 
It could be pass an argument to let itself find the xml file, or pass all the configuration pair .

Can anyone help to figure out this? 
 Thanks very much!